# Insert a table from a sheet tab to middle of a doc template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I want to add a table from a Google sheet, Tab "LG001 - Table 1" to a replacement tag of "Table 1" in a doc Template.

PS: Thanks so much for your help, I realize there might be some mistake in other steps, thus I attach the whole code here so that you have a better context of what is going on.

This code is in a sheet - Script

Here is what I have been trying:

> ```
>  function onOpen() {
>   const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
>   const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
>   menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
>   menu.addToUi();
>
> }
>
> function createNewGoogleDocs() {
>   //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
>   const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1ljyhJ11v90WQJTIV9nrjC0uq80HYK_U1aY7-dgMtNUk');
>   
>   //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
>   const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1dsrpxUihbYQQkdKx3uD5v0IDvv_CSUOS')
>   //Here we store the sheet as a variable
>   const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
>     .getActiveSpreadsheet()
>     .getSheetByName('HĐMBHH')
>   
>   //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
>   const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
>   
>   //Start processing each spreadsheet row
>   rows.forEach(function(row, index){
>     //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
>     if (index === 0) return;
>     //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
>     if (row[16]) return;
>     //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
>     const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy("LG.001 " +" "+row[15], destinationFolder)
>     //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
>     const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
>     //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
>     const body = doc.getBody();
>     
>     //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
>     body.replaceText("{{b Company name}}",row[2]);
>     body.replaceText("{{Party B Address}}",row[3]);
>     body.replaceText("{{Party B Tel}}",row[4]);
>     body.replaceText("{{b Rep}}",row[5]);
>     body.replaceText("{{B Position}}",row[6]);
>     body.replaceText("{{B Tax Code}}",row[7]);
>     body.replaceText("{{dot1}}",row[8]);
>     body.replaceText("{{chu1}}",row[9]);
>     body.replaceText("{{word1}}",row[10]);
>     body.replaceText("{{dot2}}",row[11]);
>     body.replaceText("{{chu2}}",row[12]);
>     body.replaceText("{{word2}}",row[13]);
>     body.replaceText("{{bh}}",row[14]);
>     body.replaceText("{{Contract ID}}",row[0]);
>   
>
>   function inserttable1(){
>   let sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp
>     .getActiveSpreadsheet()
>     .getSheetByName("LG001 - Table 1");
>   let numRows = sheet1.getLastRow();
>   let numColumns = sheet1.getLastColumn();
>   let data = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
>   // the id of the document file
>   let placeHolder = body.findText("{{Table 1}}");
>   let paragraph = placeHolder.getElement().getParent();
>   let index = body.getChildIndex(paragraph);
>   body.insertTable(index+1,data);
>   body.removeChild(paragraph);}
>
>   //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
>     doc.saveAndClose();
>     const pdf = convertToPdf_(doc, destinationFolder); // Convert the doc to a PDF file.
>       const url = pdf.getUrl();
>     //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
>     sheet.getRange(index + 1, 17).setValue(url)
>
>   function convertToPdf_(doc, folder) {
>   const blob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');
>   const file = folder.createFile(blob);
>   return file
>     }})}
> ```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: copy is undefined

Comment: body is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to insert a table after your marker.  I then delete the marker.

```
function inserttable1(){
  let sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let numRows = sheet1.getLastRow();
  let numColumns = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  let data = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
  // the id of the document file
  let doc = DocumentApp.openById("1......................................");
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let placeHolder = body.findText("{{Table 1}}");
  let paragraph = placeHolder.getElement().getParent();
  let index = body.getChildIndex(paragraph);
  body.insertTable(index+1,data);
  body.removeChild(paragraph);
}
```

Reference

- [Document.getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getBody())
- [Body.findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String))
- [Body.getChildIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getChildIndex(Element))
- [Body.insertTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertTable(Integer,String))
- [Body.removeChild()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#removeChild(Element))